# Is there a way for sqlc to generate code that can use pgxpool

Tags: go, pgx, sqlc

I started using recently `sqlc` with `jackc/pgx/v5`. I would like to be able to use `pgxpool` as well, but there is really no good way to use `pgxpool` after `sqlc` takes over in the flow. For instance, this is how I initialize the connection pool:

```golang
var err error
var pool *pgxpool.Pool
if pool, err = pgxpool.New(context.Background(), url); err != nil {
    log.Panicf(...)
}
defer pool.Close()

queries := db.New(pool) // queries *Queries
```

Basically, I just make `queries` available to the entire application whenever a database interaction is needed, but I don't pass around `pool`.

Moreover, since `sqlc` manages connections automatically, I'm not sure the implications of using something like the following snippet, because there are lots of manual steps involved and some overlapping:

```golang
ctx := context.Background()

conn, _ := pool.Acquire(ctx)
tx, _ := conn.Begin(ctx)
defer tx.Rollback(ctx)

queries := db.New(pool)
queries.WithTx(tx).OneOfTheAutogeneratedQueries(ctx)

defer conn.Release()
tx.Commit(ctx)
```

Anyone in the same situation? Is there a better way to approach this? I was under the assumption that the auto-generated code by `sqlc` would provide a mechanism to manage transactions accordingly, but looks like there is still a need for the pool's reference in order to create a `pgx.Tx` type, in addition to close resources programmatically as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use `sqlc` it typically generates an interface that abstracts away the underlying driver-level database connection or connection pool. this interface is named `DBTX` by default

```golang
type DBTX interface {
    Exec(context.Context, string, ...interface{}) (pgconn.CommandTag, error)
    Query(context.Context, string, ...interface{}) (pgx.Rows, error)
    QueryRow(context.Context, string, ...interface{}) pgx.Row
}

func New(db DBTX) *Queries {
    return &Queries{db: db}
}

type Queries struct {
    db DBTX
}

func (q *Queries) WithTx(tx pgx.Tx) *Queries {
    return &Queries{
        db: tx,
    }
}
```

It's important to note a few things here

1. `pgxpool.Pool` and `pgxpool.Conn` implement the `DBTX` Interface
2. `pgx.Tx` also implements the `DBTX` interface
3. The queries struct takes the `DBTX` interface, this is to abstract the operations that you might perform on a database connection or transaction

Now if it is ***your wish*** to manually manage the database connections you can set the `emit_methods_with_db_argument` option to true in the `sqlc.yaml` file. when you do so, the generated code will look as follows

```golang
// db.go
type DBTX interface {
    Exec(context.Context, string, ...interface{}) (pgconn.CommandTag, error)
    Query(context.Context, string, ...interface{}) (pgx.Rows, error)
    QueryRow(context.Context, string, ...interface{}) pgx.Row
}

func New() *Queries {
    return &Queries{}
}

type Queries struct {
}
```

Now query methods will have the following signature

```golang
func (q *Queries) CreateAuthor(ctx context.Context, db DBTX, arg CreateAuthorParams) (Author, error) {
    row := db.QueryRow(ctx, CreateAuthor, arg.Name, arg.Bio)
    // ...
}
```

Notice how the generated query methods accept a `DBTX` as a second parameter. you can pass here a single connection, a connection pool or even a transaction

> Basically, I just make `queries` available to the entire application whenever a database interaction is needed, but I don't pass around pool.

I am not sure if i understand your question correctly, but we can achieve this by simple dependency injection. you can define a struct that represents your API or APP like this

```golang
type App struct {
    Queries *db.Queries
    Pool    *pgxpool.Pool
    // Other fields such as Cache, Logger, etc.

}

func NewApp(pool *pgxpool.Pool) *App {
    return &App{
        Queries: db.New(),
        Pool:    pool,
    }
}
```

And then, in your main or wherever you're initializing the application:

```golang
func main() {
    pool, err := pgxpool.Connect(context.Background(), connectionString)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to connect to database: %v", err)
    }
    defer pool.Close()

    app := NewApp(pool)
// rest of your application
}
```

Now you can execute a transaction like so

```golang
func (app *App) addBookAndUpdateAuthorEarningsHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := r.Context()

    tx, err := app.Pool.Begin(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Failed to begin transaction", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    defer tx.Rollback(ctx)

    book, err = app.Queries.CreateBook(ctx, tx, newBook)
    // handle error

    err = app.Queries.UpdateAuthorEarnings(ctx, tx, updateEarningsParams)
    // handle error 

    err = tx.Commit(ctx)
    // handle error 

    w.Write([]byte("Book added and author earnings updated successfully"))
}
```

You will do the same for a singular query, instead of starting a transaction you will simply acquire a connection and pass that as `DBTX`.

That being said, you don't necessarily need to this, `Exec`, `Query` and `QueryRow` will acquire a connection from the connection pool and release it at the end. Without using `emit_methods_with_db_argument` we can do a transaction like so

```golang
package db


func (q *Queries) AddBookAndUpdateAuthorEarningsTX(ctx context.Context, author Author, book Book) error {
    // Start a transaction
    // The underlying type of db (DBTX) is *pgxpool.Pool
    tx, err := q.db.(*pgxpool.Pool).Begin(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer tx.Rollback(ctx)
    tq := q.WithTx(tx)
    // ... (rest of the transaction remains the same)
    // (it's important to use `tq` not `q` to execute transaction queries
    err = tx.Commit(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Using this, your app struct needs only to contain a reference to the `Queries` struct

```golang
type App struct {
    Queries *db.Queries
    // Other fields such as Cache, Logger, etc.

}

func NewApp(pool *pgxpool.Pool) *App {
    return &App{
        Queries: db.New(pool),
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation! I guess I was missing (or reluctant) to pass around any reference(s) to `*pgxpool.Pool`, because I think it should be accounted for in the code generation by default. I wouldn't like to manage the act of opening and closing transactions, but I will settle on passing `*pgxpool.Pool`, acquiring the transaction, and using `queries.WithTx(tx)` to call the generated functions.